# I need to compute as many times as remaining elements in the state in a State Monad

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, scalaz, state-monad

I am studying this example of a stack implemented with the State monad. It uses the state monad implementation in scalaz.

The example has been taken from Eugene Yokota post http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/State.html

```scala
  import scalaz._
  import scalaz.Scalaz._

  type Stack = List[Int]

  val pop = State[Stack, Int] {
    case x :: xs => (xs, x)
  }

  def push(a: Int) = State[Stack, Unit] {
    case xs => (a :: xs, ())
  }

  def stackManip: State[Stack, Int] = for {
    _ <- push(3)
    a <- pop
    b <- pop
  } yield(b)


  val res: (Stack, Int) = stackManip(List(5, 8, 2, 1))
```

I've been trying to implement a piece of code to empty the stack in a functional fashion. The definition of  `stackManip` uses `pop` two times but what if I want the number of pop to be the same as the number of elements in the state (`List[Int]`)?

The very first question to pop up would be "Why would you need that?" The answer is that I'm trying to implement a very similar case in which I need to execute pop as many times as elements in the statt. If someone can help me with the stack example then I'd be able to implement my particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call `pop` as many times as elements in the stack you can do something like this:

```
val emptyStack: State[Stack, Unit] = State.init.flatMap { stack =>
    if(stack.isEmpty) {
        State.state( () )
    } else {
        for {
        _ <- pop
        _ <- emptyStack
        } yield ()
    }
}
```

Edit: Another way, abusing scalaz:

```
type StackState[X] = State[Stack,X]

val emptyStack: State[Stack, Unit] = State.init.flatMap { stack =>
    Applicative[StackState].replicateM_(stack.length, pop)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add to the example the following `empty` definition:

```
val empty = State[Stack, List[Int]] {
    case xs => (Nil, xs)
}
```

And then change the stateManip function to use it:

```
def stackManip: State[Stack, List[Int]] = for {
    _ <- push(3)
    l <- empty
} yield l
```